# Sentences' construction

Tags: sentence-construction

Can anyone please tell me, with respect to words’ order which two sentences are correct from pairs given below?

1) It seems fine to me.

Or

1)  It seems to me fine.

2) It occurred good to me.

Or

2) It occurred to me good.

Please give a justification if possible.

Comment: you need to understand 'standard word order'. If you don't know, read it loud, which one sounds more natural? to me, it's 'It seems fine to me"

Comment: you're welcome. And also, prefer 'happened' over 'occurred' in that one! :)

Comment: Ok Maulik. I have improved a lot because of this forum and you folks.

Comment: It's same here, being an Indian. We understand each other that way. haha. Also, i recommend a Google plus page managed by me. https://plus.google.com/communities/107585603389633910293 I recommend it.

Comment: @MaulikV First of all, congrats on being the moderator of your Google Plus community. However, taking a quick look, I can see a lot of questionable things there. (For example, *I've seen non-native speakers using the phrase 'centered around'. Whoa! How can be something 'centered around'. What actually they mean is 'centered ON'.  Avoid blunders, be respected! :)* -- *It's 'must-to-read'. I had a debate with some native speakers once when they advised my 'must-have' gadget to 'must-to-have' gadget.*) Would you mind if I posted questions here, and linked to your page?

Comment: Anything is 'yes' to make all Asians (especially Indians) becoming 'learned' in this language. What is your plan, btw? @DamkerngT. Also, I did not get what you meant by 'questionable' thing over **there**. Is there anything wrong, if *yes,* please become a member and comment/correct it. That's free! :)

Comment: I'm not sure if I really have any plan. My idea is that it could be interesting to see opinions from others on those things I think questionable. It could be beneficial to all of us, and you could relay the feedback to your community, too.

Comment: Thanks for the invitation! But at the moment I think I'd stick with ELL. :-)

Comment: BTW, I only meant questionable usage when I said questionable things.

Comment: @Maulik I wonder if that kinda promoting is allowed. You do disclose your affiliation and this is a one-time comment, but I wonder if the community thinks this is acceptable.

Comment: I provided a link *(as we often do here in answers)* that helps learning the language. Yes, 'by me' is promotional but I was driven by emotions then! And most importantly, that site is *never* monetized. @inɒzɘmɒЯ.A.M

Answer (score 1):

**It seems fine to me** is the only sentence which makes sense.

> It seems to me fine.

The word *fine* is an adjective and must be attached to a verb. "It seems to be fine" is correct, "it *looks good* to me fine" is incorrect (I've replaced "seems" with "looks good" to highlight why this sentence is wrong).

> It occurred good to me

This is also wrong, even though the sentence uses the verb **to occur**!

Things can't "occur good", in the same way things can't "love good" or "run good". It could occur *suddenly* to you, because suddenly is an adverb and not an adjective.

Why is **to occur** different than **to seem**? Only verbs which describe a state of *being* can be paired with an adjective. An object can smell good, taste good, look good, and be good. Verbs which describe an *activity* cannot be paired with an adjective; an object cannot sing good, laugh good, break good, or go good.

> It occurred to me good.

For the same reason as above, it can occur to you *suddenly*, but it can't occur to you *good*.

Comment: Thank you Mark, as per my understanding 1) it seems fine to me. 2) It occurred to me good. 3) It can occur to you suddenly. These all are correct sentences. Right!

Comment: "It occurred to me good" isn't correct, **to occur** is a verb that describes an activity so it can only be paired with an adverb such as 'well'. 'Good' is an adjective so it can only be paired with verbs that describe a state of being.

Comment: Ok Mark. I have improved a lot because of this forum and you folks.

Answer (score 1):

"It seems fine to me" is correct. "Fine" is an adjective, here being used as a predicate adjective. That is, we are using a verb to link the subject, "it", to an adjective, "fine". Usually in such cases the verb is a form of "to be". Like, "It is fine" or "It will be fine". But here "seems" is being used as the connector. The connector must be a verb that indicates a state of being or transition of a state of being, such as "is", "seems", "became", etc.

"To me" is an indirect object of "seems". Indirect objects almost always come after predicate adjectives and direct objects. "He sent the package to me", NOT "He sent to me the package."

Neither of the sentences you give using "occurred" is valid. "Good" is an adjective. It modifies a noun. But it is not modifying any noun in this sentence. It is not being used as a predicate adjective here because "occurred" cannot act as a linking verb in such a sentence. You could modify "occurred" with an adverb. Like you could say, "It occurred suddenly to me". (I'm trying to think of other adverbs that make sense with "occurred". Hmm ...)

I'm not sure what you're trying to say in that sentence, so I can't tell you how to phrase it correctly.

Comment: Thank you Jay...To ensure regarding sentences' construction, I have asked here.  And, do you have any article/page where they have provided sample of sentences' construction/Frame